# Custom fill for TIKZ nodes without covering the text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanted to create custom frames for text and I decided to use the TIKZ package.

I want one textbox with the title with custom filling, i.e. not all filled, not all empty, and another textbox with the content.

This example is based on a picture I saw on another thread.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum width = \linewidth, text = white] (title) {\bfseries\Large #1};
\node[minimum width = \linewidth, anchor = north] at (title.south) (main frame) {\parbox{.95\linewidth}{#2}};

\draw[line width= 0.25mm] (title.north west) -- (main frame.south west) -- (main frame.south east) -- (title.north east);

\filldraw[fill = blue, line width= 0.25mm]
let \p1 = (title.south west),
\p2 = (title.north west),
\p3 = (title.south east),
\p4 = (title.north east) in
(\x2, \y2) arc (90:0:0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) arc (180:270:0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -- (\x3 - \y2 + \y1, \y1) arc (270:360:0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) arc (180:90:0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -- cycle;
\draw[text = white] node at (title){\bfseries\Large #1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\mybox{TITLE}{
Many paragraphs 

can 

go 

in content.
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

This produces a satisfactory result, but note one thing. I need to draw the node `(title)` first to determine the size (it could use two lines if the title is long), then draw the background and then redraw the node to show the text.

Is there a more efficient way of drawing, whithout having to draw the same node twice (i.e. without covering the text while drawing the background)?

Comment: On a related note, is it possible to compile the MWE and insert it as a picture. Or do I need to print screen and upload an image?

Comment: You may take a lot on the tcolorbox package

Comment: You have to print screen and upload image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` package might be a good approach, but for your specific code, you can load the `backgrounds` library, and then use `\begin{scope}[on background layer] \filldraw ... \end{scope}` to draw the background behind the title node.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum width = \linewidth, text = white] (title) {\bfseries\Large #1};
\node[minimum width = \linewidth, anchor = north] at (title.south) (main frame) {\parbox{.95\linewidth}{#2}};

\draw[line width= 0.25mm] (title.north west) -- (main frame.south west) -- (main frame.south east) -- (title.north east);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\filldraw[fill = blue, line width= 0.25mm]
let \p1 = (title.south west),
\p2 = (title.north west),
\p3 = (title.south east),
\p4 = (title.north east) in
(\x2, \y2) arc (90:0:0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) arc (180:270:0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -- (\x3 - \y2 + \y1, \y1) arc (270:360:0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) arc (180:90:0.5*\y2-0.5*\y1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\mybox{TITLE}{
Many paragraphs 

can 

go 

in content.
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar box with `tcolorbox`. The code is adapted from example in page 161 in `tcolorbox` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
skin=enhancedlast jigsaw, 
interior hidden,
boxsep=0pt, 
boxrule=1pt,
top=2mm, 
sharp corners,
colframe=black, 
coltitle=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
boxed title style={empty,boxrule=1pt, size=small},
varwidth boxed title=0.75\linewidth,
underlay boxed title={
\path[draw, fill=blue!70!black, line width=1pt]
(frame.north west)
cos +(5mm,-\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
sin +(5mm,-\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
-- ([shift={(-10mm,-\tcboxedtitleheight)}]frame.north east) cos +(5mm,\tcboxedtitleheight/2)
sin +(5mm,\tcboxedtitleheight/2);
\draw[line width=1pt] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east); },
title={#2},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{This is a ver very long title which uses more than one line}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]